# Pressing E yields a euro sign "€" instead. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-registry, keymap

A teacher at our high school contacted me, saying that every time she presses the E key it prints out a euro sign. It's not the language settings, I already tried that. It happens in all programs, and regardless of who's logged in. Could a student have remapped the key when she wasn't looking?

Comment: What windows ? In just some software or in every ? More info would be good.

Comment: Windows XP. Everything. Regaurdless of who'a logged in.

Comment: Sorry. Who's logged in.

Comment: So why not swap out the keyboard to test of that's been rigged?

Comment: Did you meanwhile try restarting?

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes modifier keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or the Windows key get "stuck". I didn't quite work out the *why* but sometimes it happens, as if the OS just doesn't see the key-up event.

Anyway, the usual way to get rid of that is simply by pressing all modifier keys once, so just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and the issue should go away.

It's especially annoying with the Windows key, though, as this causes programs to start on every second keypress (E for Explorer for example). On a slow machine that can be frustrating.

Comment: If the modifier keys were stuck, then other keys also were producing their alternatives (or ouput nothing if there is no alternative/special function).

Comment: While this is true, it does not match the above scenario.  What all we answers need is more information about the nationality of this keyboard and its user.

Comment: Actually the OP didn't say anything about any other keys. So where do you take the idea that other keys *aren't* affected? We simply have no data on this so all we need is somthing that explains the specific data point we *have*, which is that E produces €.

Answer (score 4):

Your suspicions of keyboard remap can easily be verified by downloading a utility like [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) which will show you all key mappings currently in effect, and can also be used to restore all defaults.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just now, in Turkey we also have the euro key mapped under E, and accessible using altGr. I tried to keyboard tricks mentioned here to no avail. The other keys seemed to work fine. I then saw that the function lock light was lit. I pressed the FnMode key on the right corner of the key, and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note: I had this problem too, and nothing seemed to solve it.
Restarting the computer didn't work, and worse, according to KeyTweak my mappings were all correct, the E key was correctly bound to letter e.

I solved this problem by unplugging my keyboard (I have a USB kb) and replugging it.
Absurd, but it worked.

I'm using WinXP SP3. I write it down here so it can help someone else in the future.

Sabrina

Answer (score 0):

It can be either a regional setting (have him change his region to an English-speaking one), or a font issue (make sure he's using a standard font and not Symbol or Wingdings :)).
Also, does this happen in every application?

Comment: Regional setting: Can't happen, font issue: possible but highly inlikely and requires some malicious intent and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I've just has this same issue on OpenSolaris. I was typing away when suddenly (after I must have hit some weird key combination) the keyboard mapping changed "e" to print "€". After bit of testing, it seems that <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> returns the mapping to normal - not sure if this will be the same on Windows on not.

Answer (score -2):

Students, female teacher, E key = euro.  I smell a rat.  Especially as the normal combination is Alt Gr (right alt) and 4.

Comment: i think Czech keyboard layout is using AltGr + E

Comment: I'm sure AltGr+E used to be the shortcut key when Euro first came along (so WIn 95 / 98 days). Possibly still the case for some layouts and keyboards.
Is it possible she has a stuck AltGr key?

Comment: This is layout-specific. The German keyboard layout has it on AltGr+E as well, as do most European layouts, I think. I am using US International here and there it's AltGr+5. On Apple's keyboard it's totally different as well. That's not something that's standardized in any way :-)